# Chance of scoring in dice game midnight (1-4-24)

Tags: combinatorics

The game midnight ($1-4-24$) involves rolling $6$ dice, keeping at least one, then rolling the remaining dice etc, keeping at least one, etc. At the end if you have kept a $1$ and a $4$, you get to score the remaining $4$ dice. If not, you score zero. So to be successful you need to have rolled both a $1$ and a $4$ during your go, and kept them.

The best strategy is therefore to keep the first $1$ and $4$ that come up, and if you haven't kept a dice this throw, keep the highest.

Wikipedia entry says that the maximum probability of being able to score (have a $1$ and a $4$) is

$$P(\text{success}) = 1-\left(2\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^{21}-\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^{21}\right) = 0.956727$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_(game)#Strategy

I get most of this formula except one piece, so I must be missing something obvious.

The $1-$$($    $)$ is just the $1 - P(\text{failing to get 1 and a 4})$

So to fail to score, you have failed to get both a $1$ and a $4$ in $6+5+4+3+2+1= 21$ rolls. The chance of failing to get a $1$ in $21$ throws is $(5/6)^{21}$, and the same for a $6$, hence the $2(5/6)^{21}$, I assume it's related to the probability of not getting a $4$ or a $1$ on a single dice, raised to the power of  $21$ throws,  but what exactly is this term and why there is a minus in front of it?

Any suggestions on what I've missed would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  In subtracting away the probabilities of having not gotten any ones and subtracting away the probability of not having gotten any fours., we subtracted too much.  So, we add back again the amount we subtracted too much of which would be the probability of having rolled neither

Comment: Bingo, thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

That additional term is precisely the probability that *neither* of $1$ or $4$ appear. Here we have two events, so let's name them:

- **Event A:** You roll no $1$'s in the $21$ rolls available.
- **Event B:** You roll no $4$'s in the $21$ rolls available.

You are trying to compute the probability of $A\cup B$ - that is, the probability that *either* of these things happen. To do this, you can use a formula, which is a simple case of the inclusion-exclusion principle:
$$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$
which states the the probability of at least one of the events happening equals the sum of the probabilities of either event happening, minus the probability that they both happen - since we, in a sense, counted the cases where *both* happen twice in the sum $P(A) + P(B)$.

As a simpler example, if you wanted to compute the probability that, if you flip two fair coins, you get at least one to land heads up, you could let event A correspond to the first coin being heads up and event B correspond to the second coin. Both events happen with probability $1/2$ - but we can't simply *add* them to get the probability of either happening, because that discounts the possibility that both comes up head. So we subtract this probability of $1/4$ to get the correct answer that you will get at least one heads with probability $1/2+1/2-1/4 = 3/4$.

In the example you give, $P(A)$ and $P(B)$ are both equal to $(5/6)^{21}$, being the probability of missing the particular number on every roll. Then $P(A\cap B)$ is the probability of missing both $1$ and $4$ on every roll, which is $(4/6)^{21}$. Thus, the probability of either not getting a $1$ or not getting a $4$ is $(5/6)^{21}+(5/6)^{21}-(4/6)^{21}$, which is the term given there.

---

This reasoning can be extended further - with some subtleties. If you had three events, you would write
$$P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)+P(A\cap B+\cap C).$$
This works because when we sum $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$, we first need to subtract out the overlaps of the cases - as we have counted them twice. However, once we've done that, we counted cases where all three happen thrice in $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)$, but then subtracted them thrice in $-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(B\cap C)$, so then have to add those cases *back* in, as we cancelled them entirely. You can keep coming up with formulas - and they're very systematic - to deal with any number of events and this tends to be a powerful technique.